# HTML5 Required field space at the end set it to invalid

Tags: html, css

I want to validate email adresses with the required attribute. But if users enter a space at the end I gets invalid again.. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/6he4b3rb/

```
<input id="email" class="validate[required] wpsg_checkout " type="email" required="" placeholder="Deine E-Mailadresse" value="" name="wpsg[checkout][email]">
```

Comment: try using Javascript or JQuery you might be able to have it ignore the " " spaces idk for sure though

Comment: By definition, when you use `type=email`, you ask for such checking where a space at the end is invalid. So what do you want?